# Register module for PerRequestLifetimeManager

Tags: model-view-controller, unity-container

I want to separate Unity configuration in my project to another project, but I have a some questions about the UnityWebActivator class in Unity configuration for MVC. 
In the UnityWebActivator class, it has this lines:

```
// TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
// Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

- But if I don't uncomment them, the PerRequestLifetimeManager seem
  still work fine. Why we must register the UnityPerRequestHttpModule?
- I found some way to register modules in Web.config file in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx). Does it
  work like DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule
  method? If not, could I register that module in Web.config file and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UnityPerRequestHttpModule is responsible for automatically disposing the instance at the end of the HTTP request.  If you don't register the HTTP Module then you **will** get one instance per request however if that instance implements IDisposable then it will not be disposed (which could cause issues).

I think that as long as the module is registered (whether via code or config) it should be fine.